# change ssh IP based on current network

Tags: ssh

I have these two entries in my ssh config on my laptop:

```
Host server1_int
  Hostname 192.168.1.92
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
  User me
  Port 1234

Host server1_ext
  Hostname 134.x.y.z
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  User me
  Port 4321
```

This server is behind a NAT. 
When I am behind the NAT as well I need to ssh into "server1_int". If I am somewhere else on the Internet I need to ssh into "server1_ext" to reach my server.
Is there a way to configure ssh such that it chooses the right entry based on the subnet my laptop is currently in?

Comment: Does your router support [hairpin nat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning)? If so you should be able to always use the external address/port.

Comment: I guess it would be easier to create command/alias that would check local ip and connect to appropriate server

Comment: @hardillb I just checked. My router does support hairpin NAT and has that enabled. For some reason I receive "Connection refused". I am guessing that is not a ssh problem, but a "settings in the router wrong - problem"

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes thats always possible, but I was hoping ssh has such a feature implemented.

Comment: If hairpin nat is set up properly it should just work, unfortunately without being able to monitor your network it's impossible to say why you are getting "connection refused".

Comment: Good thing there is wireshark. So what's happening is that ssh sends TCP SYN to my public IP + port, but my router (not the server) responds with TCP RST instead of forwarding the request to the server.

Comment: That sounds like hairpin nat is not working properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in [`~/.ssh/config`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5) (or a global client config) the [`Match`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#Match) keyword with the `exec` criteria to run a script returning a verdict (true or false):

> **Match**
>
> Restricts the following declarations (up to the next **Host** or **Match**
>   keyword) to be used only when the conditions following the Match
>   keyword are satisfied. Match conditions are specified using one or
>   more criteria or the single token **all** which always matches. The
>   available criteria keywords are: **canonical**, **exec**, **host**, **originalhost**, **user**, and **localuser**. The **all** criteria must
>   appear alone or immediately after **canonical**.
>
> [...]
>
> The **exec** keyword executes the specified command under the user's
>   shell. If the command returns a zero exit status then the condition is
>   considered true. Commands containing whitespace characters must be
>   quoted. Arguments to **exec** accept the tokens described in the TOKENS
>   section.

Let's use as verdict "Will trying this IP require that gateway? (including checking for no gateway)" put in the script `~/bin/hasthisgateway.sh` (This example script, intended for Linux, can probably be improved. Don't forget to `chmod u+rx` it):

```
#!/bin/sh
gateway=$(/sbin/ip -o route get "$1" |grep -E -o ' via ([0-9]+.){3}[0-9]+'|sed 's/^ via //')
[ "$gateway" = "$2" ] # final test and return code
```

For the first case, assuming we're in the same LAN, we want no gateway, for the second case, well that's the default remaining case, we don't need the exec criteria. While it will match when in all locations, it won't override previous values, as stated in the [man](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#DESCRIPTION):

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used.
>   [...]
>   Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more
>   host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning
>   of the file, and general defaults at the end.

But that's not enough: elsewhere the *Host* entries also tells it applies only up to the next Host *or* Match entry. So actually those Match entries get used whatever the Host by default (they should be indented at the same level as the Host entry) and we can't use a simple `Match all` either for the second case or it would set the Hostname for any other setting, including other Host settings. To avoid this, add an *originalhost* criteria:

> The originalhost keyword matches against the hostname as it was
>   specified on the command-line.

It's possible to insert more cases before the default (an other internal LAN? there's probably a specific gateway then, or choose a better criteria script).

`~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server1
  #common parts
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
  User me
  #internal
Match originalhost server1 exec "~/bin/hasthisgateway.sh 192.168.1.92 ''"
  Hostname 192.168.1.92
  Port 1234
  #external
Match originalhost server1
  Hostname 134.x.y.z
  Port 4321
```

Now in both cases, you can use the same `ssh server1` command which will behave differently. This will affect *scp*, *sftp*, *lftp* ... as well. It would probably have been possible to use only Match entries and no Host entry for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Since SSH configs cannot be scripted, the easiest way to go about this would be to set up port forwarding and always connect to public IP, or create a script for connecting to your server.

Pseudocode for bash script

```
if (ip.startsWith("192.168.1.")) {
   ssh me@192.168.1.92 -p 1234
}
else {
   ssh me@134.x.y.z -p 4321
}
```

Keep in mind that if you're connected to another network that starts with "192.168.1" the script will assume that the SSH server is reachable by local IP, which will not be the case. Only way to avoid this is to have the script check if it's actually at that IP by running a netcat header grab or something like that.